# React Context state not shared between components

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-hooks, next.js

I have been using Redux for a long time, but now decided to try out the new ContextAPI.

I got it working with one component/page (using NextJs), however the state isn't shared between pages/components.

**store.js**

```
import React, { createContext, useReducer } from 'react';
import reducer from './reducer'


const initialState = {
  players: [],
};

const Store = ({ children }) => {
  const [state, dispatch] = useReducer(reducer, initialState);
  return (
    <Context.Provider value={[state, dispatch]}>
      {children}
    </Context.Provider>
  )
};

export const Context = createContext(initialState);
export default Store;
```

**reducer.js**

```
const Reducer = (state, action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case 'ADD_PLAYER':
      return {
        ...state,
        players: [...state.players, action.payload],
      };
    case 'REMOVE_PLAYER_BY_INDEX':
      const array = state.players;
      if (array) {
        array.splice(action.payload, 1);
      }
      return {
        ...state,
        players: !array ? [] : array,
      };
    default:
      return state;
  }
};

export default Reducer;
```

**add players page /players/add (addplayerspage.js)**

```
import React, { useContext } from 'react';
import map from 'lodash/map';
import isEqual from 'lodash/isEqual';
import { Context } from '../../../context';

const PlayerCreatePage = () => {
  const [_, dispatch] = useContext(Context);
  const handleAddPlayer = () => {
    dispatch({ type: 'ADD_PLAYER', payload: Math.random() });
  };
  const handleRemovePlayerByIndex = (index) => {
    dispatch({ type: 'REMOVE_PLAYER_BY_INDEX', payload: index });
  };
  return (
    <div className="layout">
      <div>
        <Context.Consumer>
          {([state]) => {
            const { players } = state;
            return map(players, (p, i) => <div
              key={i}
              onClick={() => handleRemovePlayerByIndex(i)}
            >
              {p}
            </div>
            )
          }}
        </Context.Consumer>
      </div>
      <button onClick={() => handleAddPlayer()}>Add new</button>
    </div>
  );
};

export default React.memo(PlayerCreatePage, (prev, next) => isEqual(prev, next));
```

**lobby players page /players/lobby (lobbyplayerspage.js)**

```
import React, { useContext } from 'react';
import map from 'lodash/map';
import { Context } from '../../../context';

const PlayersLobbyPage = () => {
  const [state, _] = useContext(Context);
  return (
    <div>
      <div>
        {map(state.players, (p, i) => <div
          key={i}
        >
          {p}
        </div>
        )}
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};

export default PlayersLobbyPage;
```

_app.js (NextJs)

```
import App, { Container } from 'next/app';
import '../styles/main.css';
import Store from '../context';

class MyApp extends App {

  render() {
    const { Component, pageProps } = this.props;
    return (
      <Container>
        <Store>
          <Component {...pageProps} />
        </Store>
      </Container>
    );
  }
}

export default MyApp;
```

THE PROBLEM:

- Have two tabs open

  1. Add players
  2. Lobby
- Add a new player

  1. See that player is added on 'Add players' page

  2.See that NOTHING happens on 'Lobby' page

Answer (score 0):

Okay, so the issue is that I was trying to "**share**" context api state between different open tabs, it doesn't work like that by default, even for redux (tried adding it and faced same result), for redux there's a redux-state-sync library for that, nonetheless I will use sockets in future, so this won't be an issue.
Closed.